# What happens in the DB when a user updates a record in a versioned table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, update, versioning

*ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1/Oracle 18c.*

In a table that is versioned (with the option to move edits to base):

What happens in the database when a user updates a record?

It would be helpful to know what exact steps are performed in the database, and in what order.

Comment: The documentation covers this. If you want confirmnation, then enabling a trace and reviewing the resulting SQL for a simple edit session would provide it.

Comment: @Vince Thanks, I've read the documentation but haven't seen the details I'm looking for. And unfortunately, I don't have DBA privileges, so I don't think I can do a trace.

Comment: That actually makes it easier. Have the DBA do a trace for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly when you version a table and make an edit. It adds those changes to the managed delta tables.  So all adds and deletes are tracked in those tables.  Each edit then moves the database to a new state further down the tree.  So the underlying base state is unchanged and the edits in the delta tables are applied to those features to see the current database state.

Eventually that state tree will get very long and is the reason to compress it.  it will prune all the trees and move those edits to the base state and start over.

With the option to move edits to the base selected basically means it will handle the reconcile and posting automatically for you.

Here is an excellent versioning whitepaper with more information than you would ever care to know.
http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/Versioning_2.pdf